# grabbing and setting windowsize in windows with python

Tags: python, windows, window, size

I've searched all over, but I haven't found a way to either get the size of a certain window in windows, or setting the size after you have checked which size it is.

I'd be glad if someone could help me out where to search. I'm working in windows 10 with python and opencv as well.

I've found Selenium WebDriver, but this seems to work with browsers only. I'd like to know if it's possible for other windows than browsers, Notepad for example.

In sum, I'd like to get the size of a certain window and changing it if it's not the correct size I want it to be. Thanks for thinking with me.

Comment: do you mean the **size** of the window ?

Comment: Yes, I'll change it to size instead of resolution.. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **Module win32gui**
>
> > Python extensions for Microsoft Windows’ Provides access to much of the Win32 API, the ability to create and use COM objects, and the Pythonwin environment

---

> **MoveWindow function:** Changes the position and dimensions of the specified window.
>
> syntax: MoveWindow(hwnd, x, y, width, height, bRepaint)
>   **

```
import win32gui
#hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, 'Window Title')
hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, 'Untitled - Notepad')

x0, y0, x1, y1 = win32gui.GetWindowRect(hwnd)
w = x1 - x0 # width
h = y1 - y0 # height

win32gui.MoveWindow(hwnd, x0, y0, w-500, h-500, True)
```

**result:**

- App (full screen stretched): Notepad

[image]

- Run code (tested pyCharm,python 3.7 project interpreter)

[image]

Comment: Awesome man, I'm going to try it out, but I think this is exactly what I need, thank you so much!